# Headphone Audio Noise

Tags: audio, headphones

I built an audio mixer, and tested it with two different pairs of headphones. When I test it with one pair of headphones (I'll call Headphones #1), there is no noise (except for a few "pop" sounds when it first connects). When I test it with the second pair of headphones, there is very audible noise/crackling.

The only difference in specs that I'm aware of between the two pairs of headphones is the impedance. Headphones #1 is about 30 ohms, and Headphones #2 is lower impedance at around 8 ohms.

Given the below circuit, in which V1 and V2 are input audio signals, and the output is connected to a headphone channel, can you see a reason why noise would occur with Headphones #2? Why would a lower impedance headphone be subjected to audible noise with this circuit, or could it be due to a different characteristic?

The 1k resistor at the output is a discharge resistor I put in to prevent popping.

[image]

Comment: What op amp are you using?

Comment: It's an LME49721, datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/snas371c/snas371c.pdf

Comment: What is the nominal peak-to-peak voltage of the input signals?

Comment: The peak to peak voltage is about 100 mV. It's music playing from a phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a preamp IC. Its output current capablity is too low for 8 Ohm load and 100mV output voltage. I guess that strong bass peaks cut off everything else momentarily. The headphones are complex loads, 8 Ohms is the nominal value, the actual impedance is heavily frequency dependent and can be at some frequencies much lower.

You should use a speaker amp IC.

Comment: Wow thank you for the insight, I just noticed in the "description" section of the datasheet that the output current capability is ±9.7mA, which I didn't see in the spec section. So it has been trying to draw (nominally!) 100 mV/8 ohms = 12.5 mA...

Comment: @donut Careful: If it's 100mVpp, then the peak voltage is half that and so is the peak current. At 100mVpp (±50mVpp) it would draw ±6.25mA. Still, I think this is the right answer and your signal level is probably higher than 100mV.

Comment: Would this IC be a suitable replacement: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa6111a2.pdf   It's a 150-mW Stereo Audio Power Amplifier

Comment: @donut The pinouts are not compatible. Look at pins 3 and 5. That IC should work, but you will need a different circuit to put it in. Section 10.2 in the datasheet gives a lot of guidance on how to use it.

Comment: Ahhh thanks, just noticed that. This looks like a drop in replacement: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4808.pdf

Comment: @donut you should redesign your system for new IC, both of your alternatives will work. In your original circuit the 2nd amp stage is totally useless. Do as suggested, rely on circuits in the application notes. Mixing with resistor fork is ok.

Comment: The purpose of the second amp stage is to de-invert the output from the inverting summing amplifier. If the pinout of the LM4808 matches the pinout of my current op amp, then why would the circuit need to be re-designed?

Comment: @add at least the decoupling capacitors. The inversion of the signal is not hearable. Test it. You have no idea how many times it already has been inverted in the production chain and different parts of the audio mix surely differently. Your output dc block capacitor is quite big. For -3dB at 25Hz and 8 Ohm should half of it be enough.

Comment: I know the signal inversion can't be heard- I just need the signal to be in phase with the original signal for my application. The output dc blocking capacitance is that size because I needed a very low cutoff frequency. Thank you!